# Added a dependency, but can not import anything

Tags: android, android-studio

This is a total newb question and I believe it has a very simple solution. My problem is that an [imported dependency](https://github.com/thelittlefireman/AppKillerManager) is not accessible from my `MainActivity.kt`. I added it like any other dependency and according to the library docs. And I simply can't import the classes I need. They are missing. Any advice?

**build.gradle** (Module: MyApp)

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.thelittlefireman:AppKillerManager:2.1.1'
}
```

Rebuilding the project gives me this error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.thelittlefireman:AppKillerManager:2.1.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/thelittlefireman/AppKillerManager/2.1.1/AppKillerManager-2.1.1.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/thelittlefireman/AppKillerManager/2.1.1/AppKillerManager-2.1.1.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
```

Comment: try rebuilding the project, check internet

Comment: @AsthaGarg, this is such a pain. Rebuilding the project helped a bit, because it gave me an error `Could not find com.thelittlefireman:AppKillerManager:2.1.1`. I guess the library is not in the locations specified in the project settings and I need to add the github repo as a location?

Comment: https://github.com/thelittlefireman/AppKillerManager/issues/1 Check this. Seems this project is from maven repo

Answer (score 0):

Added `jcenter` repository (or whatever it's called) to **settings.gradle**.

**settings.gradle**

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositories {
        ...
        jcenter()
    }
}
```